# Calculating the matrix product of the elements of a table

Tags: functions, matrix

I am trying to compute the matrix product of all the elements of a table of the following form :

```
tableofmonodromy[csize_, x_, q_] := Table[ArrayFlatten[( {
   {ArrayFlatten[
      IdentityMatrix[2^(csize - i)]\[TensorProduct]a[x, 
        q]]\[TensorProduct]IdentityMatrix[2^(i - 1)], 
    ArrayFlatten[
      IdentityMatrix[2^(csize - i)]\[TensorProduct]b[x, 
        q]]\[TensorProduct]IdentityMatrix[2^(i - 1)]},
   {ArrayFlatten[
      IdentityMatrix[2^(csize - i)]\[TensorProduct]c[x, 
        q]]\[TensorProduct]IdentityMatrix[2^(i - 1)], 
    ArrayFlatten[
      IdentityMatrix[2^(csize - i)]\[TensorProduct]d[x, 
        q]]\[TensorProduct]IdentityMatrix[2^(i - 1)]}
  } )],{i, 1, csize}];
```

such that the definition of a,b,c,d is the following :

```
a[x_, q_] := ( {
    {(1/2) (x q - (x q)^-1) , 0},
    {0, 1/2 (x - x^-1)}
   } );

b[x_, q_] := ( {
    {0, 0},
    {1/2 (q - q^-1), 0}
   } ); 

c[x_, q_] := ( {
    {0, 1/2 (q - q^-1)},
    {0, 0}
   } );

d[x_, q_] := ( {
    {1/2 (x - x^-1), 0},
    {0, (1/2) (x q - (x q)^-1) }
   } );
```

Basically I am creating a series of 2x2 matrices with elements that are also matrices (operators) and storing them.
Now that I have all my matrices inside of the table, I want to compute the matrix product of all of them.

My first approach was to do : `Dot@@tableofmonodromy[csize,x,q]` which gave me the error Dot: Tensors. I knew that it wouldn't work because my desired product is of the following form:

```
tableofmonodromy[3,x,q][[1]].tableofmonodromy[3,x,q][[2]].tableofmonodromy[3,x,q][[3]]
```

My second approach was to store the elements of the table (tableofmondromy[[i]]) in a list using a for loop, like so :

```
dummyarray=Array[f,csize]
For[i = 1, i < csize + 1, i++,dummyarray[[i]] = ArrayFlatten[tableofmonodromy[csize, x, q][[i]]]];
Dot@@dummyarray
```

Which worked for calculating the product however I lost the "function" aspect of my calculations.

Is there a way to calculate the product of all of the elements of the table without losing the "function" aspect of the calculation and getting the result  also as a function ?

Comment: Hello, when I copy-paste your code for the function "tableofmonodromy", I see that there is a missing comma near the end "--- ]*here*{i, 1, csize}]". After inserting the comma, when evaluating tableofmondromy[3,x,q] I receive an error from ArrayFlatten.

Comment: Do the functions a, b, c, and d have definitions as well? If so it might be easier to help if their definitions are included.

Comment: I just copy pasted exactly the code on my mathematica sheet. In all cases my problem is not specific to my code. I just want to know in case I have a table that has elements and these elements are matrices. How do I make the product of all these matrices (that have the function structure) and end up with a matrix that has also the function structure \

Comment: yes a,b,c,d have definitions I will add those as an edit. (they are matrices as well and funcitons)

Comment: There might also be an error in Dot@@dumyarray as maybe it should be Dot@@dummyarray (mm instead of m )

Comment: @user293787 It wasn't really clear to me at first thanks for clarifying it !

Comment: @userrandrand thanks for you feedback !

Comment: Perhaps `Dot@@Map[ArrayFlatten,tableofmonodromy[3,x,q]]`? Regarding "getting the result also as a function", perhaps `newFunction[csize_,x_,q_] := Dot@@Map[ArrayFlatten,tableofmonodromy[csize,x,q]]`.

Comment: @user293787 YES ! thank you so much ! can you put your answer as a response so that I can confirm it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `For`-loop given by OP can be replaced by [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) as follows:

```
newFunction[csize_,x_,q_] := Dot@@Map[ArrayFlatten,tableofmonodromy[csize,x,q]];
```

For example, calling

```
newFunction[3,x,q]
```

produces a certain $16 \times 16$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure this question is a duplicate, or more like a `ConstantArray["dupli-",{100}]<>"cate"`... Anyhow, welcome to `Map`-world.